# How to extend Numpy array class with append() function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class

How can I achieve:

```
>>> foo = np.array([1,2,3])
array([1,2,3])
>>> foo.append(4)
array([1,2,3,4])
```

Instead of numpy's:

```
np.append(foo, 4)
```

I've tried stuff along the lines of:

```
import numpy as np
class myarrayclass(np.array):
    def append(self, value):
        self.object = np.append(self.object, value)
```

Also, is it possible to overwrite the numpy class instead of creating my own?
I don't *need* this to work, just wondering if it is possible, thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the code of `np.append` before you try this. It is not a list `append` clone, and shouldn't be treated as one.

Comment: The closest thing to list append is the `resize` method.  That can add zeros in-place.  It may be instructive to look at the code for the `np.resize` function, which does not operate in place. Rather it uses `concatenate` and `reshape`, making a new array.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best way, but here is one approach.

```
import numpy as np

class myarrayclass(object):
    def __init__(self, in_array):
        self.array = in_array
        
    def append(self, val):
        self.array = np.append(self.array, val)
      
    def show(self):
        return self.array
        
        
foo = np.array([1,2,3])


myarray = myarrayclass(foo)
myarray.append(5)

myarray.show()
#Out[7]: array([1, 2, 3, 5])
```

When you make an object, you need to initialize it with `def __init__(self, in_array)`.  Here I have included a simple append and show method.  I included the show method to demonstrate that the append worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Sadly this isn't really extending the numpy class, and causes you to lose all its functionality. I want to add a function to the already existing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The code in dubbbdan's answer definitely has its value but I would suggest the implementation below:

```
import numpy as np

class MyArrayClass(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.ndarray.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super()

    def append(self, item):
        return np.append(self, item)
```

The devil is in the details and that answer is not actually extending the numpy.ndarray class but creating a class wrapper for the append function.